# copying values of a dataTable to another DataTable with different clumns

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable dt1` that contains this columns : PRODUCT_ID,MIN_VALUE,MAX_VALUE,AMOUNT
and another `DataTable dt2` that contains this columns : ID,MIN,MAX,POINT_TO_ADD

dt1 contains multiple rows that I want to copy them to dt2 how can I do that ?

Comment: I don't think there's any OOB functionality to do that, other than looping the Datatable. But would it be a possibility to do that directly through database queries/stored proc ? I don't know what you want to do with this new datatable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
foreach (DataRow sourcerow in dt1.Rows)
{
    DataRow destRow = dt2.NewRow();
    destRow["ID"] = sourcerow["PRODUCT_ID"];
    destRow["MIN"] = sourcerow["MIN_VALUE"];
    destRow["MAX"] = sourcerow["MAX_VALUE"];
    destRow["POINT_TO_ADD"] = sourcerow["AMOUNT"];
    dt2.Rows.Add(destRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<dt1.Rows.Count;i++){
   DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow();
   dr["ID"] = dt1.Rows[i]["PRODUCT_ID"];
   dr["MIN"] = dt1.Rows[i]["MIN_VALUE"];
   dr["MAX"] = dt1.Rows[i]["MAX_VALUE"];
   dr["POINT_TO_ADD"] = dt1.Rows[i]["AMOUNT"];
   dt2.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```